# executing model procedure within different (not related) model in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

Within a cakephp website i got the following models

- Items
- Categories
- Subjects
- etc

On items/item i want to show a donation form. For example
items/item/?id=1234

```
<h1>item name</h1>
<p>item description</p>


<br />
<p>Would you like to make a donation?</p>
<form method="post" action="???">
<input type="text" name="ccNumer" />
<input type="text" name="ccExpiry" />
<input type="text" name="ccName" />
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Since `donations`  has no relationship to `items` and can also be used in `categories` or anywhere else, i'm not sure how to do this the proper way. Should it maybe be a component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which version of cakePHP you are using so I am assuming cakePHP 2. You can load any other class in your any class just as you can in vanilla PHP. To include another model you would do following

```
App::uses('Donation', 'Model');     // first parameter being your ModelName and second the path
```

Now you can use the methods of the model by instantiating an object.

```
$donationObj = new Donation();
$donationObj->methodName();
```

More on this here on official documentation.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html

Comment: @bicycle And if you're only using the result of a single method, it can be simplified further to; `$result = ClassRegistry::init('Donation')->methodName();`. `App::uses(...)` is not even required then.

Comment: @thaJeztah great! yeah even better! yeah that model only has one method anyway. it's basically a soap method to send the cc details to a ws

Comment: What @thaJeztah said.  Using `new Model()` will only give you an instance of the code in that class. It will not work as a Cake model (e.g. access to the db, helpers, etc). This should not have be the accepted answer.

Comment: @Costa not entirely sure, but I think the Model's constructor should initialize the Model to a useable state (see the [source](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L673)), so either solution should work. ClassRegistry does have the advantage that it will re-use an existing instance if it exists and the code is probably a bit cleaner. Will rewrite my comment to an answer if I have a bit of time later on

Answer (score 1):

To easily access a Model anywhere in your application, use `ClassRegistry::init()`. (See:
[ClassRegistry](http://api.cakephp.org/2.3/class-ClassRegistry.html)). `ClassRegistry::init()` will initialize a Model ready to be used.

For example, to access a method of a model;

```
$result = ClassRegistry::init('Donation')->methodName();
```

Or to get an instance of a Model;

```
$MyModel = ClassRegistry::init('Donation');

$result  = $MyModel->methodName();
$resultB = $MyModel->anotherMethod();
```

Adding `App::uses(...)` is not even required, ClassRegistry should take care of that.